# Is app-release.apk zipaligned apk?

Tags: android, zipalign

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2. 
When I click assembleRelease in gradle tasks, two files are generated, app-release-unaligned.apk and app-release.apk. I know app-release-unaligned.apk is unaligned but what is app-release.apk? Is it aligned apk? My build.gradle is like below.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        zipAlignEnabled true // Is this necessary or not in Android Studio 1.0.2?
    }
}
```

Even if I didn't put zipAlignEnabled true, app-release.apk is generated.
Is it still necessary in Android Studio 1.0.2?
All information I get about zipalign is before Android Studio 1.0 comes out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is both aligned and signed.
Ready for publication.

AFAIK `zipAlignEnabled` is true by default for release builds.

Comment: OK. But even if I omit zipAlignEnabled true line, app-release.apk is generated. Is that line necessary?

Comment: AFAIK `zipAlignEnabled` is true by default for release builds.

Answer (score 22):

You don't need to set that flag.

From [official guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types)

> The possible properties and their default values are:

[image]