# Google Play - Fully Shadowed apk

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an existing app on the PlayStore. I am releasing new version of the app as **staged rollout**. However, I am not able to publish the app due to "Fully Shadowed APK" error.

[image: Fully shadowed APK error]

So far, I haven't found any documentation as to how to resolve this error. Anyone else faced this?

Comment: may be version code is old version compare to playstore version code.check both version codes

Comment: @Hanuman I triple checked this. Both version code and version number are greater.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update :-**
Talked to a Googler working with Google Play console team regarding this issue. One misconception I had at the time was that you need to retain an APK if you want to have a staged rollout. I discussed this with him, and he clarified that it is not needed. Even in staged rollout, with no retained APK, Google  play will show an install option to users who visit the app's page. Hope this clears doubts for someone facing similar issues.

I was having the same problem and I fixed without clicking "Retain" for previous version and uploaded a new one and then "Start Rolling" button turn into clickable and done!! ^_^

Comment: This is what has worked for us for now, hopefully there will be a better solution known to someone, this feels like a hack rather than a solution.

Comment: which channel? Production / beta / alpha ?

Comment: I see this is the accepted answer, but i don't understand what you actually did to make it work.  What does it mean to not click 'Retain' for previous version?  Where are you seeing this 'Retain' option?  I go to my app release, browse for an apk, upload it then review and i see the error.  I don't get a retain or do not retain option anywhere.

Comment: @ Dallas Caley I also having same problem how you solved..please help me sir

Comment: @DallasCaley @GowthamanM Sorry to not reply earlier, I didn't get notification for some reason. When you start a new release, 'Prepare release' section, you have a section called `APKs to retain`, you can see the retained APK there.

Comment: If you're trying to promote your apk from other tracks, don't do it from track management. It'll automatically retain previous version. Just go for new release and "Add From Library".

Comment: I still don't understand what you did to solve the issue? I do understand that we don't have to retain any older version but what has to be done to enable `Start Rolling` button again then? @RohanKandwal @apple appala

Comment: @Eren Utku For some reason, when we were retaining the old APKs, we were getting the 'Fully Shadowed APK' error and weren't able to proceed further. Once we stopped retaining the old APK, the error went away.

Answer (score 21):

The Play Console has a bug and that's why it doesn't work. This is the work around:

Say, you have two versions:

1. Beta: 29
2. Alpha: previously version 29, but now empty: 'Promoted to beta’ it says. You want to upload version 30.

Then do this:

1. Create a new Alpha release with version 30, and deactivate the previous APK. When you try to roll it out, it errors Fully shadowed APK.
2. Go back a page and now remove version 30. Version 29 will be selected, click Save and Start roll out to Alpha. This only deactivates 29.
3. Create a new Alpha release for 30, it should work now.

Comment: Lol, we faced the same issue and did the same.. and Issue resolved.
Seems that there is some bug in play store release manager

Answer (score 15):

**Note: this solution works for the time it was posted if doesn't work in the future don't consider it wrong because things changes with time.**

You have to deactivate previous version while uploading a new APK that works for me. Simply deactivate previous versions and upload a new APK and roll it out for production.

Comment: As a last resort I did that and it worked. However, I wanted to have a staged rollout which I couldn't do. Any ideas about this error?

Comment: I think now they are only allowing a single active APK that would be the latest one with the highest version code or may be its a bug on their side but i don't think so its a bug most probably they are just restrict to a single active APK at a time.

Comment: I understand but in that case how will staged rollout work? Staged rollout requires an older version of the app to be active on the play store isn't it?

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked the following way:

- First send a rollout **only** with the version you want to deactivate.
- Secondly, send a rollout with the version you want to publish to Beta.

Seems that under certain conditions Google Play cannot handle deactivating and publishing at the same time.

Comment: Worked for me too. One major problem is that the error message is very unhelpful. And I don't see this mentioned in the help sections either. On top of that I had to switch my browser to English, so that the error message was searchable... sigh...

Comment: I actually wrote support, let them know about the bug and they told me it has been sent to the team. Whether that will lead to a fix, can't say it.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same issue and resolved it by using the following versionCode entry in config.xml:

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
  version="3.1.1"
  android-versionCode="3001001"
```

Here **android-versionCode** is critical. It must be an integer **greater than** the number associated with last APK that you have uploaded. Due to some reason my previous version had an additional zero in between creating a higher number which went unnoticed. Since I can't change that because its published I added a zero in the new versionCode and made it 3001001 instead of 300101.

Worked perfectly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This solved the same issue with my ionic app! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Got the same problem here, issue most probably brought by the new release manager.

It feels like that the previous release (the one already in prod) is somehow stuck in alpha, preventing the new one to be rolled out.

Google support contacted and waiting for resolution
(I'm working for an app with +25millions downloads, this issue is really something serious, hope google will take care of it really quickly)

In the meantime, we never used the beta channel, so we solved our problem by using it.

Comment: we're having the same problem - but we usually upload to beta then release to production. The promotion to production is now not working and showing the "Fully Shadowed apk" error. I've uploaded to alpha - now waiting 20 minutes to see if I can promote it to production.(This is actually a PITA because our QA are set up on the beta channel and I don't want to spend time setting up the alpha channel now)

Comment: promoting from Alpha channel to production seems to have worked. Hopefully the beta channel won't remain FUBAR'ed for long

Comment: We had been waiting for answer from Google support for weeks now, hopefully you will have a better luck. Do update the answer if you find a permanent solution to this.

Comment: Google support replied to us within a day saying issue is fixed...and issue is indeed fixed. Hope they'll be as reactive for all of you as they were for us! Bon courage :)

Answer (score 6):

Easy way to handle this problem is something similar like,
[image: Need to follow like this]

Seems bugs on play store

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Comment: @Regis_AG feel free for production release version and live on store already, your any testing environment will not affect intentionally or automatically to your current production release version, production app will remove or update only when you intentionally try to do it

Comment: @KirtikumarA., how to deactivate apk? I have no buttons for that. For some reason, string that you highlighted is "1 app bundle retained" for me

Comment: @EvgeniiVorobei You should have the option there to deactivate unwanted apk

Comment: @KirtikumarA., I do not have the option. Nobody does, because Console the same for everyone. Even at the screenshot you provided, there is no any buttons.

Comment: @EvgeniiVorobei It seems you need to check the option there, if you still facing challenges then please contact me back via my email and I will connect with you

Answer (score 5):

We ran into this problem as well with split APKs. We assigned version code for each ABI with the following gradle (simplified):

```
ext.abiCodes = ['universal': 0, 'arm64-v8a': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'x86': 3, 'x86_64': 4, ...]

android {

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
      def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
      def abiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(abiName)

      output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode * 100 + abiVersionCode
      ...
```

With that we will have these APKs:

```
| ABI       | Version Code |
|-----------|--------------|
| universal | v100         |
| arm64-v8a | v101         |
| arm64-v7a | v102         |
| ...       | ...          |
```

And we got this "Fully Shadowed APK" error on APK v101. The reason is that any device that is on `arm64-v8a` will be able to install v102 since it is backward compatible.

Problem solved after we make the version code of `armeabi-v8a` higher than `arm64-v7a`.

```
ext.abiCodes = ['universal': 0, 'arm64-v7a': 1, 'armeabi-v8a': 2, 'x86': 3, 'x86_64': 4, ...]
```

You should watch out for this too.

Comment: Were you able to upload a universal apk supporting X abis when you also have X split apks supporting one abi each? I had to include the useless armeabi in my universal but not split on it in order to include the universal without the fully shadowed error.

Comment: @sbaar yes, that's what we are doing for our releases. We include both the universal and the split apks.

Comment: @sbaar here is a more complete version of our Gradle file not sure if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44359115/1035008

Comment: I'm facing the same error. Tried but this solution does not work for me.

Comment: This was a lifesaver, thank you so much. I accidentally uploaded in the "correct" order for a while, then today ran into these bewildering errors. I would have never guessed putting x64 before x32 version would cause those messages (?!?!)

Answer (score 4):

Problem:

This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.

Resolution:

Remove this APK from your release or review the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in this release.

I got the same error when I tried to update my app. The Project was old and was in Eclipse, I fixed it by decreasing targetsdkversion from 27 to 26, because imported, supported android lib was Android 7.1.1, I don't know how it worked, but it works for me. :D

Comment: For us, target SDK etc were same and Version codes were higher. Then too we got this error.

Comment: Are you still getting this error, if yes, give me more details- project is in eclipse or studio?

Comment: That was long time ago for a client project, it was fixed as said in checked answer.

Answer (score 3):

in your release manager you see your last uploaded apk  and on your apk  you see the word ***retain*** click on it  scroll down page  then you see Deactivate option then click on it then upload your new apk again the n save to draft and review it then roll out and after that just wait .

Answer (score 3):

Just remove you previous version from the console and upload the latest one then it will definitely work it won't try another time.

Answer (score 1):

For sure there is some kind of bug in Google Play Console. In our case we've uploaded the new APK directly in Production. Clicking on "Review" button leaded to the "Fully Shadowed apk" error message.

Then we've done the following with the APK that we wanted to publish and was uploaded as draft in Production:

1. Delete it from Production.
2. Upload it in Beta and then delete it.
3. Upload it in Alpha and then delete it.
4. Upload it again in Production.

After the last step the error message didn't appear again. It is not clear which of the steps helped to overcome the issue. Probably it is enough just to delete and upload it again, but I cannot be sure since I cannot reproduce it again.

I wish you luck! We all need it in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Just discard the current release then go back to create new release then select apk or aab file from your library(which apk or aab version was showing error) then save the file now you will not get error.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you don't have **multiple versions** of your **app bundle** uploaded. For example, if your last released version was v1.7 and you uploaded v1.8 but didn't publish it on the Play Store, and now you are trying to upload v1.9, you might encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well i face this issue today, i solve it by remove the old version from the `Include app versions from your previous release` and click next now the problem is gone
[image]

**EDIT**

Side note:
My error message was slightly different

`This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes. Remove this APK from your release or review the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in this release.`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The issue seems to be resolved after removing the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It says - other APKs have higher version code.  So you probably have a released APK that has a higher version code than your new APK.  So increase your new APK to a higher number.  You can see your other APK version codes on the android console.  And change in your `config.xml` in the `widget` section

```
<widget android-versionCode="999" id etc...>
```

Comment: That's not the case, the issue was that we had retained a older version of the apk which was causing issues with newer APK. Asked a Googler working on Google Play team about this, they recommended not to retain older version of SDK unless the older version has some hardware/software difference from current version .i.e. it targets some more/less devices than the newer APK.

Comment: your error says other APKs in the release has higher version codes. If that is not the problem there is little point posting your incorrect errors.  You had to retain an APK or there would only be one release, therefore 1 version code.  The issue the retained apk was causing was that the old APK had a higher version code than the new APK. That is what your error says.  The answer from Google Play does not fix the error, just stops it showing as there is only one APK hence no higher version code. Either this is the answer or Google's errors are lying to you

Comment: As I said, I talked to a Googler who accepted that the error message was confusing. He told me he'll note down the issue and simply the message, don't know if that is done. As you will see with so many other answers, it's a bug on Play store side, not app version issue, if you see the green part of the message you will see v31 is being uploading but v30 is shadowing it. Let me know if there is still confusion.

Comment: your comment to the selected answer was that you wanted a solution not a hack.  Is it possible the Googler did not understand the error message. Cristofori did not play piano as well as beethoven.

Comment: Don't know, he was from the Play console team, met him in a GDD conference. What he told me, satisfied me, btw, the the version code and number were always higher in the new release, i'm not that stupid. Anyhow, this is feeling more like a fight now so I will stop responding anymore, have a great day and thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, have a great day and thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Discard all the Apps and upload a new one with increasing Version Code.

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution of this problem.
just disactivate the older version of the apk then you will be able to rollout the new version.

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Answer (score 0):

Our case is that we are pushing two APKs: Once for 32bit arm and one 64bit arm (due to Google's new [requirements](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit). We were seeing this same problem whenever the arm64-v8a APK had a smaller version code than the armeabi-v7a one.

Thus **making sure that the arm64-v8a version had a higher `versionCode` than the armeabi-v7a version solved this problem for us**.

Answer (score 0):

You must build in this way to solve the problem

```
First: armeabi-v7a
Second: x86
Third: arm64-v8a
fourth: x86_64
```

Like this:

```
3000467 - armeabi-v7a
3000468 - x86
3000469 - arm64-v8a
3000470 - x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you previously retain any apps below the uploaded APK list in upload form , just deactivate it then goto 'review' your app. because if you retain any app it will not removed after uploaded another app , so the previous should be list in apps to deactivate table.

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Answer (score 0):

All I did was update the version and the bundle code. My version had been set at .13 and I changed it to 15. My Bundle was set to 13 and I changed it to 15. It let me post it fine after I did that. I am in open testing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you have to deactivate previous version of app. Now when uploading new version if there is retain option in old version do nothing just do the process and it will be done But if ther is option of deactivate in old version click that deactivate old version and now upload the app

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution to this is to remove the universal apk only if you face this issues in 2021 will uploading multiple apk to playstore .