# Fully shadow apk issue on newly released app

Tags: android, google-play, apk, abi

i am having issue with multiple split abi upload to google play and i already tried the solutions to previous questions but they did little to no good to me.

below is my build.gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 24
//    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'unikey'
            keyPassword '*****'
            storeFile file('E:/Projects/CompanyDroid/AppSigner/mykey.jks')
            storePassword '*****'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    //buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aethtech.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    splits {
        abi {

            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            versionNameSuffix '1.0'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

the error in google play store looks as below:

[image]

another one:

[image]

is there something wrong with the version code or abi split, i am new to android studio so i am unable to find any clues to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `targetSdkVersion`  to `26` , Latest `targetSdkVersion`  is `26` and your `targetSdkVersion` is `27` higher than latest one.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html

One thing remember every time once you upload release apk on play store always increase the versionCode higher than previous one.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.aethtech.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

or check this,
Are you using multiple apk in the play store? Or even if you are using one apk but use the splits gradle function, that is considered "multiple" apk to the play store. I think that error can be avoided using a version code scheme like the one described here.https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#VersionCodes

Comment: still same issue when trying to review, did the changes but no solution :(

Comment: Create new project on your android studio and compare gradle with that app gradle.

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408046/google-play-fully-shadowed-apk

Comment: ok also i tried generating universal apk but its also generating same size as my other abis identical size 3.75 mb that should not be happning as universal abi contains all right?

Comment: have to checked out that url ? i commented

Comment: i am following version code scheme `project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]` check this line do you think this scheme is wrong, i mean as per google the shadow apk must have version higher then other app to resolve issue maybe thats the cause?

Comment: Why you are using  project.ext.versionCodes  ?? in your project

Comment: and this https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle file says:

```
// Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK 
// that includes all ABIs.
```

But then it has

```
universalApk true
```

Is it possible you are uploading a universal APK, and this universal APK is shadowing all your other APKs?

Also from your gradle file I'd expect to see 4 APKs uploaded (one for each native ABI) but you are uploading 2. This looks wrong as well.

Comment: no i am not uploading unversal apk, i did make that true just for testing purpose

Comment: at first i tried uploading all 4 but when i got this issue i deleted the draft from play store and tried uploading and review one by one to see if issue was coming for each apk and it was there

Comment: do you actually have any native code in your app? If you don't the APKs will all be more or less identical and shadow each other

Comment: thanks @nick Fortescue that was exactly the issue with my app, coming from xamarin background i didn't noticed that only apps with native libs have diff. architecture requirements

Answer (score 0):

> You need to Put your Gradle in this Format. (Be Specific ***ABI Version***
> ***Code Order***)

```
splits {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true
            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.
            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()
            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true
        }
    }
ext.abiCodes = ['x86': 3, 'x86_64': 4, 'armeabi-v7a': 5, 'arm64-v8a': 6, 'armeabi': 1, 'mips': 2]
```

Comment: Did he not do this?

Comment: No, He didn't. I had same issue, then I applied above code.

Comment: Oh I see, do you mind having a look at a question I asked Yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253127/generate-apk-for-different-architectures-ffmpegmediametadataretriever