# Fully shadowed APK When try to publish apk in play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I want to publish my app to Play store. but i faced some strange problem, i don't know what i should to do.

When i was upload App Bundle file app.abb and tried to upload apk-released.apk file, the play store console said me

"Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1."

The screenshot is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6xP8lGMfUoQh9EcC98BvO2KS_m49tas/view?usp=sharing

Then i was changed the version code to 2

the code is here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    // buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.banglaralonews.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
```

then it's uploaded fine but there occurred another strange problem the console said "Fully shadowed APK" 
Screenshot is there:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pBXk1NvxPB_Wqe6IH4b8-vHb-SNwvx3/view?usp=sharing

then i was delete the project again and again i was tried like this but the same problem. so please help me to publish my apk.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to retain your previous APK (version code 1), which you don't need to. Just deactivate the older version of the APK then you will be able to rollout the new version... Also, always check for existing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408046/google-play-fully-shadowed-apk) on the same topic.

Comment: Actually this apps have no previous version this app is a new apk . and also i tried with Version Code 1000 10001 like this but still the same problem occurred .

Comment: Hugo is right. You probably opted to keep the older version in the release, which you should not.

Comment: You explicitly mentioned on your question getting the message: `Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1` on the Play Store which means that you actually have a previous version of the app. After deactivating that previous version and you should be fine. Try that and update your question if not.

Comment: Thanks but the older apk is the production version. If I deactivate it in the alpha or beta tracks, will it remove the production version ? See the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652630/google-play-console-does-deactivation-of-production-code-version-in-alpha-or-be

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to change the version code 2.4 -->2.5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I did not encounter such a problem, but I would try to make versionCode higher than usual, for example 10 or 20. And versionName 2.0.
I remember I forgot what version I already had in the Google Play store and randomly set 16 to accurately overcome the limit and I managed to do it successfully.

Comment: Making the version code to 10 or 20 would definitely not resolve the issue and neither changing the version name... that's just a speculation, not a technical proven answer.

Comment: this is really just a guess :(

Comment: Actually i tried version code 1000 10001 also the same problem occurred