# Include old version play console

Tags: include, updates, google-play-console

Delete this threat if there is already one existing but I didn’t find it with the search function or it didn't help me out.

I tried to upload an update of my app.

I have an issue uploading on play console

My abb version that's currently online is called 113.
Now I want to make an update that's called 114
But I want to include version 113

Here is what the console gives me as error

*This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes. Remove this APK from your release or review the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in this release.*

I saw this errors in boards but the solutions there didn't help me since I work with App Bundles and not APKs

Comment: Add your code, your question is extremely unclear. I am not sure what to help you with please read our how to ask a good question page. We need code and debugging details

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408046/google-play-fully-shadowed-apk

Comment: Well this post doesn't exactly help. I can't deactivate my older version since its the main version and I need it to be included not deactivate it

Comment: Might want to talk to a Googler working with the google console team. They might help you better